# My custom Wordpress plugin is ignoring the <!--more--> tag

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to figure out I can only execute my plugin on the single post page rather than the main index page.  It is ignoring the  tag which I thought would resolve this issue.

Currently, this is how it is working:

`add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin');`

I tried detecting the  but it would return false all time.  I thought it would be removed on the single post pages:

```
if (strpos($post_content, '<!--more-->')) {  
            return false;
    }
```

There is probably a better hook for this but I am definitely a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this right after `the_post();`

```
Global $more;
```

or right before you call the_content;

By the way, the best way to make sure that something is not ran on the homepage is by check if it is the home page. Try this:

```
if(!is_home())
{
 // Run Plugin
}
```

Comment: Check this page for other conditional tags: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: +1: Solution to stated question, and the _proper_ solution too. Nice!